# How do I discard a release in Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console

I accidentally uploaded a release to the Production track that was supposed to go to a testing track. I re-uploaded it to the testing track.

When I go to Publishing Overview, there is a button that says "Send 2 changes for review". I do not want to send the production change for review, but I can't figure out how to delete it, or how to only send the test build.

Comment: Did you manage?? How on earth is this just not one button click away in 2023. Unreal.